# Is it possible to give an intuitive idea of the notation at the base of the transition Kernel for a Markov Chain on a general state space?

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains, intuition

Given $A \in \sigma(\mathcal{S})$, with $\mathcal{S}$ is the state space, the transition kernel is a function  $K(\cdot , \cdot): \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S}) \to [0,1]$

- $\forall x \in \mathcal{S}, K(x,\cdot)$ is a probability measure;
- $\forall A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S}), K(\cdot,A)$ is measurable.

If the process at the initial time (t = 0) starts from a fixed state $x_0$:
$$Pr\{(X_1,X_2) \in A_1 \times A_2\}=\int_{A_1 } K(y,A_2)K(x_0,dy)$$
**is it possible to give an intuitive idea of the concepts: "probability measure" and "measurable" and then give an intuitive idea of the meaning of the following notation?**
$$\int_{A_1 } K(y,A_2)K(x_0,dy)$$
in particular of
$$K(x_0,dy)$$
?

Comment: Probability is already a word very intuitive.  I recommend you Ross' introductory probability book for intuitive explanations if you don't mind his approach of sacrificing mathematical rigors for probabilistic interpretations.

Comment: I've got to study on Ross and the concepts of Markov chains and probabilities of transitions I am quite clear. But I can not interpret the following general notation: $K(x_0,dy)$ and I asked if it was possible to have an intuitive idea

Comment: Regard dy as an infinitesimal "neighborhood" at y.

Comment: And regard this integral as a convolution.

Comment: So being $K(\cdot , \cdot): \mathcal{S} \times \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S}) \to [0,1]$, in this case is it same things to write $K(x_0,z)$ with $z=y+dy$? With $z \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{S})$?

Comment: And is it the same thing to write: $\int_{A_1 } K(y,A_2)K(x_0,y) dy$ ?